# Are constraint checks on partitions in postgres always a good idea?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a table partitioned by month in postgres where the following are true:

- Records are never updated.
- New records are only added with the current time, give or take a few minutes.
- A trigger handles inserts so records only go into this month's partition or last month's.

Do constraint checks on the partitions / child tables help me here? Since the trigger handles the end-of-month period, it seems they would be redundant and thus unhelpful, but I feel I might be missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constraints are needed for the query planner, it uses the constraint to know where to find specific data. See the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html).

Comment: Thanks - it was because I was reading that page I asked this, actually. I don't understand a lot about how the query planner works - is it that the trigger is a black box to the planner but the constraints aren't?

Comment: The trigger is't doing anything on a SELECT, but the queryplanner is. And yes, the queryplanner knows about the contraints and they are used in the queryplan. See the results from EXPLAIN with or without a constraint and with or without a WHERE condition that matches this constraint.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't event thinking about SELECT - that makes sense. Thanks!